# Regular expression in Vim to match group capture

Tags: regex, vim

I want to find the words which **contain** the same string repeated twice.
(e.g. `wookokss`(ok/ok), `ccsssscc`(ss/ss)).
I think the expression is `\(\w*\)\0`.

Another try is to find the words which **consist of** the same string repeated twice. My answer is `\<\(\w*\)\0\>`. (word beginning + grouping(word) + group capture + word ending)

But they don't work. Could anybody help me?

Comment: I made 2 mistakes.One is using `*` because of **empty** string. Another is using `\0` to represent the whole string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1.) words which contain the same string repeated twice. (e.g. wookokss(ok/ok),

To find words containing two or more repeated word characters try

```
\(\w\{2,}\)\1
```

`\1` matches what's captured in first group.

> 2.) find the words which consist of the same string repeated twice...

To capture `\w\+` one or more word characters followed by `\1` what's captured in first group

```
\<\(\w\+\)\1\>
```

should be about it. [Have a look at this tutorial](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_patterns).

Answer (score 5):

To find a string repeated twice in a word, which is longer than two characters, you can use

```
/\(\w\{2,}\)\1
```

To match a whole word which contains beforementioned string, you can use

```
/\<\w\{-}\(\w\{2,}\)\1\w\{-}\>
```

Little bit of explanation

- `\1` - matches the same string that was matched by the first sub-expression in `\(` and `\)` (`\0` matches the whole matched pattern)
- `\{n,}` - matches at least `n` of the preceding atom, as many as possible
- `\{-}` - matches 0 or more of the preceding atom, as few as possible
- `\w` - the word character (`[0-9A-Za-z_]`)
- `\<` -  the beginning of a word
- `\>` - the end of a word

More in [`:help pattern`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html)

Answer (score 1):

For the first one use `(.{2,})\1` example here: https://regex101.com/r/gK0mM2/2
That is assuming that you only look for duplicate strings that have more than 1 character.

and for the second one `^(.{2,})\1$` example here: https://regex101.com/r/lC2yT7/2

Edit: changed the second expression, it now also looks for strings with at least 2 characters

Comment: It's just too bad that the syntax used by the regex101 site has nothing to do with the syntax used by Vim regexes.

Comment: @SatoKatsura, you might like to check out Vim Regular Expressions 101 then.  http://vimregex.com/

Comment: @BrianTiffin (1) It doesn't make the answer correct, and (2) the vimregex.com site looks like a badly outdated introduction to Vim regexes (f.i. there's no mention of look-around assertions, or of the tremendously useful `\zs` and `\ze`).

Comment: Points taken @SatoKatsura.  Thanks for the warnings, I usually use that page for quick reminders, having very low levels of regex fu